# Unknown column type "json" requested running Doctrine 2 migrations

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, database-migration

Some background about my application:

- ZF2 application
- doctrine/dbal v2.5.12
- doctrine/orm  v2.5.6
- doctrine/migrations v1.5.0

**Problem**: if I run a command `migrations:diff` to generate migration from changes in my entity classes, I get the following exception:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException] Unknown column type "json" requested. 
Any Doctrine type that you use has to be registered with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(). You can get a list of all the known types with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypesMap().
```

Answer (score 7):

The issue is that `doctrine/dbal` version `2.5.x` had no support for JSON fields in MySQL.

Bump the version of `doctrine/dbal` in your `composer.json` to `^2.6` and it should work. Make sure to **check for compatibility-breaking changes** in the [release changelog](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/v2.6.0/UPGRADE.md)

Comment: Be aware that you will need php 7.1 or higher for that.

Answer (score 5):

The problem was because old column in database had a comment `(DC2Type:json)`. I changed it to `(DC2Type:json_array)` and it works.

Why this problem occur? While doctrine is calculating the DIFF between entity mappings with database columns and actual database columns, Doctrine parses MySQL column comment (`(DC2Type:json)`) and validates `json` type. Since from newer Doctrine versions, you must use `json_array` instead of `json`, Doctrine library throws an exception.

Comment: To be honest it's opposite. Type `json_array` [is deprecated](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#json-array) since DBAL 2.6 and you should use only `json`.

Comment: I second the comment. I believe older versions of doctrine created these fields with a DC2Type:json_array comment. This worked fine on doctrine 2.6+, it didn't complain about them or offer to update them in a schema update. But, come doctrine 3+ it will no longer work on schema updates, and I had to manually update the DC2Type:json_array comments to DC2Type:json